# Initialize vba class member variable with Range

Tags: excel, vba, object, constructor, initialization

I have created a class with one of the member variables is of type range.  Now if I try to initialize or set the value of that range I error: Object Variable or with block variable not set.  Now I thought it was because it get initialized as Nothing but if I use the class sub Class_Initialize and try to set a default there, it still errs. So what gives?

```
Private pRng As Range
Private pstype As Boolean

Public Property Get Rng() As Range
    Rng = pRng
End Property

Public Property Let Rng(Value As Range)
   pRng = Value
End Property

Public Property Get Stype() As Boolean
   Stype = pstype
End Property

Public Property Let Stype(Value As Boolean)
    pstype = Value
End Property

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    pRng = Range("A1")
    pstype = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to use the Set keyword to initialize or set the range, e.g., :

```
Set Rng = pRng
Set pRng = Value
```

Comment: Because VBA assigns default properties to objects, you need to use the Set statement for objects.  This lets Excel differentiate between rng the range or rng with it's default rng.value.